Use TDirectory.GetFiles to get the newest file in a folder
I want to get the name of the newest file in a folder by using TDirectory.GetFiles in code. This is what I tried, but this doesn't always return the newest file's name because the predicate function doesn't get called in timestamp sequence.
var
  FLastTime: TDateTime;
  searchResults: TArray<String>;
begin

  FlastTime := 0;
  FPollDir := 'c:\tempfiles';
  FFileExt := '*.xlsx';

  searchResults := TDirectory.GetFiles(FPollDir, FFileExt,
    TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly,
    function(const Path: String; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
    begin
      if (SearchRec.TimeStamp > FLastTime) then
      begin
        FLastTime := SearchRec.TimeStamp;
        Result := True;
      end;
    end);

Is it possible to do this using TDirectory, or should I use FindFirst rather?

Any reason you don't want to simply get the array of all files, sort the array on the desired timestamp, and then pick the last one (if it exists)?

Good question that I also asked myself. How do I get an array of files that have timestamp attributes, when GetFiles very specifically only returns an array of filenames?

Sorry, I had hoped there were some overload which didn't return only filenames, but also file metadata fields like file sizes and dates, but apparently there isn't.

Hence my question! Now I'm going to wonder why GetFiles is so primitive and resume my use of FindFirst.

I agree one would expect TDirectory.GetFiles (or some other part of the IOUtils API) to handle this scenario easily, but that appears not to be the case, sadly.

It'll work, in as of that it'll always be the last entry in the list that is the newest file (assuming that GetFiles returns the list in the same order that it calls the anonymous method).

It doesn't. Mathias B's answer is accepted below. I guess you got to think laterally sometimes.

You need to remember the name of the newest file found so far. Do that using a simple variable.
Also, you can let the predicate function return False, which means "don't include the current file in the search results". This does not affect the end result, but saves a bit of memory while your program is running. You don't need the search results (the array of all files), because you're interested in only ONE file -- the newest one.
The code would look like this:
var
  FLastTime: TDateTime;
  searchResults: TArray<String>;
  FNewestFile: string;

begin

  FlastTime := 0;
  FPollDir := 'c:\tempfiles';
  FFileExt := '*.xlsx';

  searchResults := TDirectory.GetFiles(FPollDir, FFileExt,
    TSearchOption.soTopDirectoryOnly,
    function(const Path: String; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
    begin
      if (SearchRec.TimeStamp > FLastTime) then
      begin
        FLastTime := SearchRec.TimeStamp;
        FNewestFile := SearchRec.Name;
      end;
      Result := False;
    end);


What if the newest file found last time has been deleted in the meantime?

If the newest file may get deleted while the search runs, and that is a problem, then you have to add checks to handle that. All kinds of additional scenarios are possible.

Of course! Setting Result to False ensures that GetFiles checks every file in the folder that matches the mask. This also means that the searchResults array is empty after execution of GetFiles, but that doesn't matter. Tested. Works. Marked as the answer.

Since the searchResults will always be empty, there is no point in declaring that variable.

This isn't going to do what you think. Every time it finds a newer file, it's going to add it to the searchResults array. So if they're in the order they were created, the results will look like a random subset of files.
If you only want the latest ONE file, you're going to need to do this differently. I'd get the entire list of files first without the predicate method. Then iterate through that array using the same logic as the predicate looking for the newest file.
Alternatively, use the logic you're using and then sort through the searchResults array to find the newest one. You'll have a shorter list to go thru on your second pass.
However, be sure to save the searchRec in an outer scope each time you find a newer one, so when the loop terminates, it contains the details on the newest file.
Also, do a test to ensure you can't have multiple files with the same timestamp. (If it's one-second granularity, that can happen. If it's milliseconds, then it's not as likely.)

Thanks, but this isn't an answer. An answer would include the code to get the list, and then sort through the array of strings while comparing their missing timestamps! (geddit)

thanks, but there are multiple ways of doing this. What I explained would take a half-dozen different coding examples that would end up obscuring what I actually explained. The language I used is called English, and it's far more flexible in some cases than programming code.

Look, the answer is above and has been marked as such. More to the point, this has been added to a production program that is now in daily use.

more to the point, there are multiple ways to solve the problem, and the "accepted solution" is only one. If the purpose of this platform is to teach, then ALL of the various methods should be eligible as "accepted solutions" and they would ALL be displayed. But a few paragraphs explaining them is a lot simpler than long detailed listings that vary in a few key places. If you only want to teach simple solutions as if they're the only option, that's fine. But don't attack me for posting a more generalized description instead of a half-dozen different code examples.

The point here David, is that I had a specific question, not a general question. The way SO works is you ask a specific question with code and request specific answers that include code. This is not a forum. There are other forums, like Praxis for example.
